# How do I write an 'if' statement with PyroCMS Lex tags?

Tags: pyrocms, pyrocms-lex

Here is my 'if' statement in a loop. Sometimes the description will exist and sometimes it will not. But all I am getting is the word `LIKE` and not `ME` when the description actually exists.

```
{{ description }}
{{ if description }}
    ME
{{ endif }}
LIKE
```

Comment: How do you know ``{{ description }}` exists?

Comment: In my loop, I am passing either an array of contents or an array of events..and the description only exists in the array for events.

Comment: If you ever get Lex parser code that doesn't work, be sure to test it in isolation first on a very simple page / partial; there are bugs and it can behave unpredictably on pages with multiple or nested loops/conditionals.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
{if ('{pyro:page:is_home}' == TRUE)}

ME
>
{else}

LIKE

{/if}
```

Comment: This is the very old syntax of PyroCMS tags. Now you have to use double brackets `{{ }}`.

Answer (score 0):

If `description` can be evaluated to `true`, `{{ if description }}` **may** work.

But to test if a variable actually exists (~ is not null), you can use the keyword `exists`, like this: `{{ if exists description }}`.

If you are not sure that `description` always exists, you should also put it inside the 'if' scope, like that:

```
{{ if exists description }}
    {{ description }}
    ME
{{ endif }}
LIKE
```

Take a look at these links of documentation:

- [Lex parser Github repo](https://github.com/pyrocms/lex#checking-if-a-variable-exists)
- [PyroCMS documentation about Lex tags](http://docs.pyrocms.com/2.2/manual/guides/pyrocms-tags#checking-if-a-variable-exists)

Answer (score 0):

Need space between quote in condition "" to " ", And it's work.

> ```
> {{ if description!=' ' }}
>       True
> {{ endif }}
> ```